# Woocommerce products editable by their author for specific user role

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-post-type

I have different users registered on my WordPress website with different roles. Apart from the rest of users, I want to allow advertisers (users with advertiser role - advertiser is a custom role that I have created) to place their own products on my site and also manage them. But they need to be limited only to manage (create, edit and delete) their own products, not of others.

So far, I have tried the following code but it seems to be not valid. I am sure I can accomplish my goal using pre_get_posts action and the following function can help me but I need some help in resolving the issues with this code. I am not sure about the post type of products.

Here is the code that I am trying to accomplish my goal with:

```
function show_specific_advertiser_products( $query ) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( is_admin() && in_array ($query->get( 'post_type'), array( 'woocommerce_products' ) ) && !user_can( $current_user, 'administrator' ) ) {

        $query->set( 'author__in', $current_user->ID );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'show_specific_advertiser_products' );
```

Any help will highly be appreciated.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec will you please help me in showing products to specific users only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error in your code comes from the `post_type`… for woocommerce products it's simply `product`. You will have to replace `administrator` by your custom user role.

So try the following instead:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'show_specific_advertiser_products' );
function show_specific_advertiser_products( $query ) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( is_admin() && $query->get( 'post_type') === 'product' && in_array('administrator', $user->roles) ) {
        $query->set( 'author', $user->ID );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

Comment: I am still able to view all products, from an advertiser account. I have updated the code you provided to me and have replaced administrator with advertiser but still, it does not work.

Comment: @teccraft I have replaced `author__in` with `author`… try it again,… For me it works now and display in admin order lists only the products which I am the author.

Comment: is there any way for removing the navigation links above the table which are showing products related to an advertiser?

Comment: Like we can use the code `remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=page' );` for removing the menu items on sidebar for a specific user.

Comment: @teccraft You should better ask a new question, don't you think…

Comment: Sure, I am asking a new question. Thanks for your support

Comment: here is my new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54891028/remove-hide-the-navigation-links-above-the-woo-commerce-products-table-for-a-spe)