# How to let an influencer see their own WooCommerce coupon stats?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, user-roles

I have a client that uses WooCommerce and makes coupon codes for influencers to share. Now he wants to give the influencers a login that only shows the stat for their particular coupon code within the Marketing tab.

I know how to make a custom user role, and how to limit their access to only the Marketing > Coupons screen. But how do I set a filter on what coupons to show per user?

Comment: View: [Display only products from the logged in author on WooCommerce admin products list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62153785/display-only-products-from-the-logged-in-author-on-woocommerce-admin-products-li) and [Woocommerce products editable by their author for specific user role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54886051/woocommerce-products-editable-by-their-author-for-specific-user-role) where `post_type` = `shop_coupon` instead of `product`

Comment: @7uc1f3r That would only work if they would create the coupons. But they are only allowed to view them, not edit them in any sense. Otherwise they could increase the discount and other weird tricks.

Comment: I understand, what you could do is instead of limiting access to the existing coupons, create a new page, via a new menu item. Where you can even choose between visible/accessible via front end (my account) or back end (wp-admin). Where you display the coupons without them being customizable. That way you can immediately determine what is/is not possible via that custom page.

Comment: @7uc1f3r Thanks for the suggestions. I already have a working option with a front-end page, but I was wondering if and how I can do it in the exact way as described in the question.